# Read Tags from XML Data with Batch Script

Tags: api, batch-file, cmd, wget

I am open to suggestion for what I am trying to do, but end game: use a windows 'wget' command to download weather API from weatherbug and grab that xml data and store it to an offline xml file, then read it using batch scripts.

I could get it to work correctly using:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=><" %%i IN ('findstr /L "aws:temp>" wb_weather.xml') 
    do set cTemp=%%i
```

But only is the XML is formatted like this:

```
<aws:temp units="&deg;F">43.9</aws:temp>
<aws:temp-high units="&deg;F">62</aws:temp-high>
<aws:temp-low units="&deg;F">41</aws:temp-low>
<aws:temp-rate units="&deg;F/h">0</aws:temp-rate>
```

Once I use the 'wget' command to grab the data from the website the data looks like this (assuming all one line):

```
<aws:temp units="&deg;F">43.9</aws:temp><aws:temp-high units="&deg;F">62</aws:temp-high><aws:temp-low units="&deg;F">41</aws:temp-low><aws:temp-rate units="&deg;F/h">0</aws:temp-rate>
```

and the code I have from the above will not work correctly.

I am very new to this whole API and batch script coding, but I use batch scripts because the next part of this project (classified) will need it in batch script format.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend against using batch for processing XML. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1946768/1630171) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have a lot more flexibility if you can parse the XML *as* XML and not just a bunch of garbage you have to scrape away to get to your data.  To that end, allow me to suggest a hybrid batch / JScript solution.

This has the added benefit of giving you the ability to grab the XML feeds via `XMLHTTP` requests, removing the dependency for `wget` or similar.

Save the following file as `weather.bat`, modify the API code and zip code as appropriate, and give it a shot.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: batch script portion

@echo off
setlocal

set "apicode=A1111111111"
set "zipcode=55555"
set "url=http://api.wxbug.net/getLiveWeatherRSS.aspx?ACode=%apicode%&zipCode=%zipcode%&UnitType=0&OutputType=1"

for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%url%" ^|^| goto :EOF') do (
    set "%%a=%%b"
)

echo Temp: %awstemp%
echo High: %awstemphigh%
echo Low: %awstemplow%
echo Rate: %awstemprate%

echo;

:: show all variables beginning with aws and their values
set aws

goto :EOF

:: JScript portion */

function die(txt) {
    WSH.StdErr.WriteLine(txt.split(/\r?\n/).join(' '));
    WSH.Quit(1);
}

var x=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
x.open("GET",WSH.Arguments(0),true);
x.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
x.send('');
var timeout = 60;
for (var i = 20 * timeout; x.readyState != 4 && i >= 0; i--) {
    if (!i) die("Timeout error.");
    WSH.Sleep(50)
};

if (!x.responseXML.hasChildNodes) die(x.responseText);

// Note: These dom nodes are appropriate for getLiveWeatherRSS.aspx and
// getLiveCompactWeatherRSS.aspx.  For parsing other feeds, change the
// root XPath node appropriately.
var dom = x.responseXML, dom = dom.selectSingleNode('//aws:ob') || dom.selectSingleNode('//aws:weather');

var out = [];
for (var i=0; i<dom.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (dom.childNodes[i].hasChildNodes) {
        var item = dom.childNodes[i].nodeName.replace(/\W/g, '');
        var value = dom.childNodes[i].text;
        if (/rate$/.test(item) && value && value > 0) value = '+' + value;
        var units = dom.childNodes[i].getAttribute('units') || '';
        out.push(item + ' ' + value + units.replace('&deg;','°').replace('"',''));
    }
}
WSH.Echo(out.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=><" %%i IN (
'type wb_weather.xml^|sed s/\x3e\x3c/\x3e\x0d\x0a\x3c/g^|findstr /L "aws:temp>"'
) DO ECHO %%i
```

Could work for you - if you can use SED.

SED replaces `><` with `>[CR][LF]<` rendering the format that you find works.

Google GNU SED...

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: **`and the code I have from the above will not work correctly`**.

Excuse me, did you made a test of this point?

Your code indicate to take the second token from the only line that ends in "aws:temp>". However, if the other lines are combined with the first one in the order you shown above, then the data you want is still placed at the *second token* of the new long line that includes the four previous lines. This mean that your original code should still work correctly!

If the data you want were placed in another line, you just need to change the "tokens=" number to take the data at its new position in the long line. For example, "tokens=5" will take the temp-high data in the second line.

If the data file just contain the result of four lines, then you don't need to use `findstr` command!

Antonio